# Are long oxygen molecules possible?

Tags: molecules

Are large oxygen containing molecules possible? Either large rings, or chains with hydrogen atoms at the ends. Like this:

$\ce{H-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-$\cdots$-O-O-O-O-O-H}$

Comment: Related: [Why does sulphur, but not oxygen, catenate?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/431/why-does-sulphur-but-not-oxygen-catenate)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_oxygen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraoxygen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxygen

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, they are possible; several have even been detected.  They all have the general formula $\ce{H2O_{n}}$ and belong to the class of [hydrogen polyoxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_polyoxide).

Of course, the $n=1$ member of the series is water $(\ce{H2O})$, and the $n=2$ member is hydrogen peroxide $(\ce{H2O2})$.

The $n=3$ member is [trioxidane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trioxidane) $(\ce{H2O3})$, and it has the following structure:

[image]

It can be prepared in a number of ways as outlined in the linked article, such as the reaction of ozone and hydrogen peroxide. Trioxidane is also an active antimicrobial ingredient. Trioxidane has a half-life around 16 minutes in organic solvents, but only milliseconds in water.

[Hydrogen tetroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_polyoxide) ($n=4$, $\ce{H2O4}$) is also a known compound as is [hydrogen pentoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_polyoxide) ($n=5$, $\ce{H2O5}$).  Hydrogen pentoxide is formed as a byproduct in the preparation of trioxidane.

[This abstract](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja971534b) of a computational study provides bond dissociation energies for the hydrogen polyoxides. Starting from water, they steadily decrease (the $\ce{O-O}$ bonds become weaker) to $\ce{H2O6}$ and then start to increase again.

Abstracts from other computational studies dealing with the expected structures and stabilities of these molecules can be found [here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/qua.22695/abstract) and [here](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00268976.2014.928385).

Comment: [A recent paper in the *Angewandte*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/anie.201504084) claims to even have synthesised pure $\ce{H2O3}$ as a white crystalline solid. — G. Strle, J. Cerkovnik, *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2015**, *54*, 9917.

Comment: Wow!  Hopefully no (in)flammables were around ... .